# How to install 'clang++' on OS X

Tags: macos, clang

I've have got a default *clang* and *clang++* in the */usr/bin/* directory. Both of them is version 3.3.

Also I've installed clang with help of [this specification](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). After installation, I've gotten additional a binary utility `clang-3.5`. But `clang++-3.5` was not installed.

How can I install it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect all you were missing was libstdc++ but trying to figure that out without seeing your build log is impossible. Especially as you say 'after installation...' when there's no installation step in the instructions you link to, only build?

So, I'm going to suggest you use brew to do the install along with the dependencies. llvm35 is a bit bleeding edge but the current instructions that install that with `brew` are:

Step 1: make sure you have a recent enough gcc/libc to build clang (may not be necessary for you):

```
$ brew install gcc47
```

Step 2: install the HEAD version of llvm35 with all the trimmings (see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues/340 - you MUST read this, because we are building HEAD versions the instructions might be updated tomorrow. Correct just now, I just built it!):

```
$ brew install isl --HEAD
$ brew install --cc=gcc-4.7 --HEAD llvm35 --with-asan --with-clang --with-libcxx --rtti --all-targets
# wait....
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm35/HEAD: 1427 files, 240M, built in 18.3 minutes

$ /usr/local/Cellar/llvm35/HEAD/bin/clang++-3.5 -v
clang version 3.5 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Note my command differs from the one in the link by including `--cc=gcc-4.7` to use the gcc installed in step 1; if your gcc is already good enough, you won't need that. This is installed keg-only so won't be in the usual paths (see: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ, by 'Cellar' they mean /usr/local/Cellar; I've shown the path mine built above)

Comment: What do you mean missing libstdc++? Is it an additional option for configure script or make command?

Comment: I was referring to the instructions you linked to, step 7. As I said, I'm not going to get into the game of guessing what you've done wrong without seeing a log, but if your build *did* create clang++ and you've just mislaid it, you'll find a line like "> llvm[4]: ======= Finished Creating Debug+Asserts Alias clang++" in your log.

Answer (score 14):

As of now you can just do

```
brew install llvm
```

For me this installed llvm and clang 4.0.0 to `/usr/local/opt/llvm`

Comment: Didnt work for me, trying to `asdf install python 3.6.2`
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no

Comment: Yeah because you need to add it to your PATH.

Comment: is it fine if i install `brew llvm` then install it with port as well (`sudo port install clang)` ?

Comment: Probably ok since `brew` doesn't add LLVM to your `PATH`.