# Updating the package "matrix"

Tags: r

Sorry, I am a beginner in R. The package `ez` should be worked with the package Matrix 1.2.7.1. However, when I try to update Matrix, I face some problems.

I made use of OSX system, I have tried:

1. Directly updating in RStudio
2. Install the package with the following commands:

```
install.packages("/Users/apple/Downloads/Matrix_1.2-7.1.tar", repos = "NULL", type = "source")
```

The error messages are:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
>
> ld: library not found for -lgfortran
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
>
> *removing >‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Matrix’
>
> - restoring previous >‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Matrix’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package ‘Matrix’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
`‘/private/var/folders/j3/52_wq50j75jfk5ybg6krlw_w0000gn/T/RtmpTXNuGy/downloaded_packages’`

Thank you for the help.

Comment: **library not found for -lgfortran clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004399/how-to-install-clang-on-osx

Comment: `Matrix` is a base package, you don't have to install it.

Comment: Thank you for the concern. The problem is solved just after I update R..... I am sorry for my stupidness.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some google searching I found a potential solution, try opening your console and installing xcode, close R, reboot, then install matrix again.

```
xcode-select --install
```

It looks like you are missing the -lgfortran library. xcode may resolve your problem. If that does not work, there is a few other potential fixes I found [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1939).

Comment: Thanks you for the concern. I solve this problem just by updating R. I am sorry for my stupidness.....

Answer (score 0):

I just installed latest version of R (R-4.2.2.pkg) and it worked.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS chip M1, there is the latest R version 4.3.2. After installing the latest version and restarting the R session, 'Matrix' package is installed and it worked :)